# Checkbox link - display inline and float left not working

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mailchimp

I am connecting a Mailchimp signup form to my Wordpress website https://thetekworks.com - however the GDPR checkbox isn't performing as I had expected... having looked around the link to my privacy policy should appear after my checkbox but it appears on a new line.

I have tried using the float and display tags to correct this as I found online but this hasn't worked either.

```
<p>
<input type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Email address*" required />
    <label>
      <input style="float:left; display:inline" name="AGREE_TO_TERMS" type="checkbox" value="1" required="">
      <a href="https://thetekworks.com/privacy-policy/" target="_blank">I have read and agree to your privacy policy</a>
</label>
```

I had expected it to behave similar to https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_checked

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

After looking at your site directly, try using the following `CSS`:

```css
.mc4wp-form-basic label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

After adding that, I see the following result:

[image]

---

I think you need to organize the layout from the parent element (`<p>` in this case). Using `flexbox`, we can stack the email `input` and the `label`(s) and remove the need for `float`. I also made part of your terms link plain text, so that the `label` is actually clickable, and not just a link. Clicking a label's text should toggle the checkbox state with which it is associated.

```css
p {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

[type="email"] {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Email address*" required />
  <label>
      <input name="AGREE_TO_TERMS" type="checkbox" value="1" required="">
      I have read and agree to your<a href="https://thetekworks.com/privacy-policy/" target="_blank"> privacy policy</a>
  </label>
  <label>
      <input name="SOMETHING ELSE" type="checkbox" value="2" required="">
      Another checkbox label
  </label>  
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help - I have implemented these changes although they have had no impact?